# Java in Eclipse, using replaceAll for int int

Tags: java, string, int, replaceall

I'm working on code for a Java project, I currently have `replaceAll(String, int)` in the code block of `public String getDAT(int col, int MULTIPLIER)`. Eclipse is saying `replaceAll` is for `(String, String)` and not `(String, int)` how I'm trying to use it.

However the only suggestions are to change it to either `replace()`, `replaceFirst()`, or to change `MULTIPLIER` to a `String`. I can't do the last because it must be an integer. When I change it according to those first two, the error is essentially the same. I'm pretty new to Java so I don't know too much about it.

Here's that code block (ignore `ChatColor` and `ConfigManager`, they go with the rest of the code):

```
public String getDAT(int col, int MULTIPLIER)
  {
    String RESULT = this.LANGUAGE_DATA[this.LANGUAGE][col];
    RESULT = RESULT.replaceAll("%murk%", ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + ConfigManager.Murk() + ChatColor.WHITE);
    if (MULTIPLIER > 0)
      RESULT = RESULT.replaceAll("%mult%", MULTIPLIER);
    return RESULT;
  }
```

**Help! I still don't have a working answer here! I've added `String.valueOf(MULTIPLIER);` but it changes none of the problems with replaceAll. Is there supposed to be something else added with `String.valueOf(MULTIPLIER);`?**

Comment: Any particular reason your variables are in upper case? Normally when I read code I expect constants to be in upper case and variables to be lower case.

Comment: Probably just my non-existent knowledge of Java format and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace MULTIPLIER with one of those:

`(new Integer(MULTIPLIER)).toString()`

`Integer.toString(MULTIPLIER)`

`String.valueOf(MULTIPLIER)`

`MULTIPLIER + ""`

Comment: Okay, but then I get  - Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int   - Syntax error on token "+", invalid AssignmentOperator 
And still have my original error

Comment: Oh wow didn't realize those were each separate options, sorry. I'm trying that at the top line inside the block, is that how it should be? Still not doing anything, or I simply don't know enough...

Comment: Figured it out with some help from a fellow dev. All I had to do was put it on the same line as `RESULT = RESULT.replaceAll("%mult%", String.valueOf(MULTIPLIER));`. -_-